# google.books.load() is not defined. Included books/jsapi.js file in html

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Books = () => {
    let google = window.google;
    return (
        <div id="map" style={{ height: "500px" }}>
        {google.books.load()}
        {google.books.setOnLoadCallback(function initialize() {
            let viewer = new google.books.DefaultViewer(
            document.getElementById("map")
            );
        viewer.load("ISBN:1491918039");
        })}
    </div>
    );
};

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        show: false
    };

    showBook = () => {
        let val = this.state.show;
        this.setState({
            show: !val
        });
    };

    render() {
        let disp = null;
        if (this.state.show) {
            disp = <Books />;
        } else {
            disp = null;
        }
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button onClick={this.showBook}>click me</button>
                {disp}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Can you try this {google.books && google.books.load()}

Comment: Can you make sure the jsapi file is included before your code? If `window.google` is undefined, it means the code didn't run yet

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. Hiding what looks like an error message in the title of the question is not great. Let's see the text of any errors and messages in the body of the question itself.

Comment: The viewer must be displayed and hidden on button click. The viewer is not displayed I don't know what the problem is. The source file included in index.html is <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/books/jsapi.js"></script>.